# How to set the values from view to model?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have my jquery in mvc, to get values from view and set into model values.But i cannot achieve.
Note: verified with "alert" method values are getting perfect.
kindly tell me how achieve this.
My code looks like,

```
 $('#AssignButton').button().click(function () {
        var $selectedRows = $('#NotAllotedStudentsGrid').jtable('selectedRows');
        var selectedRowsList = [];
        var i = 0;
        $selectedRows.each(function () {
            var record = $(this).data('record');
            selectedRowsList[i] = record.UserNo;
            i++;
        });
        var LimitQuestionCount = $("#LimitQuestionCount").val();
        if (selectedRowsList.length > 0) {
            var options = {};
            options.type = "POST";
            options.url = "/Dashboard/AllotQuestionSet/";
            options.data = JSON.stringify({ selectedStudents: selectedRowsList, model: { Effective_date: $("#Effectivedate").val(), Expiry_date: $("#duedate").val(), LimitQuestionCount: $("#LimitQuestionCount").val() } });
            alert($("#Effectivedate").val());
            alert($("#duedate").val());
            alert($("#LimitQuestionCount").val());
            alert(selectedRowsList);
            options.dataType = "json";
            $.ajax(options);
            alert("ajaxCall");
            window.location.href = "/Account/ApplInfo/";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Added option.contentType,

```
      //Assign selected students
    $('#AssignButton').button().click(function () {
        var $selectedRows = $('#NotAllotedStudentsGrid').jtable('selectedRows');
        var selectedRowsList = [];
        var i = 0;
        $selectedRows.each(function () {
            var record = $(this).data('record');
            selectedRowsList[i] = record.UserNo;
            i++;
        });
        var LimitQuestionCount = $("#LimitQuestionCount").val();
        if (selectedRowsList.length > 0) {
            var options = {};
            options.type = "POST";
            options.url = "/Dashboard/AllotQuestionSet/";
            options.data = JSON.stringify({ selectedStudents: selectedRowsList, model: { Effective_date: $("#Effectivedate").val(), ExpiryDate: $("#duedate").val(), LimitQuestionCount: $("#LimitQuestionCount").val() } });
            options.dataType = "json";
            options.contentType = "application/json";
            $.ajax(options);
            alert("ajaxCall");
           // window.location.href = "/Account/ApplInfo/";
        }
    });
```

Verified.Gives perfect result.